# Dispatcher in c++

Tags: c++, operating-system

I'm working on assignment which requires us to replicate a dispatcher switching processes in c++. I haven't found anything useful so far, apart from the fork function which frankly doesn't seem much relevant either. Are there any default functions that allow for the sequential switching of functions?

Comment: Have you tried searching for the "dispatcher" design pattern?

Comment: Read up on `std::map` and *function pointers*.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, i did try searching for the dispatcher design pattern but failed to find anything relevant. I'm rather new to c++, so I hope I'm not making a complete fool of myself by asking how will function pointers help?

Comment: You need to *dispatch*, or change execution flow, to other functions.  A pointer to a function will allow you to do things like create an array of functions to be called and iterate through the slots (dereferencing a function pointer will execute the function).  The `map` allows you to associate functions with *something* like a name or number.  A *dispatch table* for lack of better terms.